# Spring : XML Configuration Location

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-ioc

I am learner of spring have build my test project with spring IOC container and have configure beans.xml in my project root path and load into my application and get bean from it.

spring.xml in project root directory

```
BeanFactory bean = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("spring.xml"));
```

spring.xml in source file

```
BeanFactory bean = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("src/spring.xml"));
```

this is another code to load beans.xml file

```
ApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```

my question is that is there any standards or conventions for creation of xml file name and location of file in real project.because in some reading articles i also found that there might be multiple xml files for large project like service.xml and dao.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be useful to have bean definitions span multiple XML files. Often each individual XML configuration file represents a logical layer such as defining DAO beans etc. in your architecture but you should always place your XML configuration files under src/resources and access them as

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"services.xml", "daos.xml"});
```

From the Spring's Manual:

> You can use the application context constructor to load bean definitions from all these XML fragments. This constructor takes multiple Resource locations, as was shown in the previous section. Alternatively, use one or more occurrences of the  element to load bean definitions from another file or files. For example:

```
<beans>
  <import resource="services.xml"/>
  <import resource="resources/messageSource.xml"/>
  <import resource="/resources/themeSource.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: and where we will reside these file in Web application directory structure.